# GAP - Finding Number of Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gap

I am new here, new in abstract algebra as well. I am currently trying to find number of subgroups. Did some search and I have the following:

gap> x:=DirectProduct(c3,c9);

gap> Sum(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(x),Size));

10

gap> List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(x));

[ Group(  of ... )^G, Group( [ f3 ] )^G, Group( [ f1 ] )^G, Group( [ f1*f3 ] )^G, Group( [ f1*f3^2 ] )^G, Group( [ f3, f1 ] )^G, Group( [ f3, f2 ] )^G, Group( [ f3, f1*f2 ] )^G, Group( [ f3, f1*f2^2 ] )^G, 
  Group( [ f3, f1, f2 ] )^G ]

I have two questions:

1. Is the way to find number of subgroups correct? It is right in this example but I am not sure if it is correct for all.
2. When I use List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(x)), it gives a list of groups. But I am not sure what is it representing? For eg, Group( [ f3, f1 ] )^G means?

Thank you.

Comment: In addition to Jack's answer, `List` in `List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(x))` is redundant since `ConjugacyClassesSubgroups` already returns a list. The 2-arg. version of `List` makes sense when you have a function to apply to each element of the 1st argument. Cf. also `AsList` and `AsSSortedList`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes. You can use the shorter form `Sum(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(x),Size);` as well. Personally, I like using the slightly more expensive `LatticeSubgroups(x);` which tells you how many subgroups there are and how many conjugacy classes (it also calculates a lot more).
2. `^G` means “conjugacy class”. `f3` and `f1` are elements of `x`. `f1` is the generator of `c3`, `f2` is the generator of `c9`, and `f3 = f2^3`.

In your case (assuming you didn't use counterintuitive names), `x` is an abelian group and there is not much difference between a subgroup `h` and its conjugacy class `h^G = [ h ]`.

Also notice GAP doesn't keep track of names internally. The elements of `x` are named after a group `f` that was used to construct the direct product, and the conjugacy classes are labelled by `^G` using `G` as a generic name for a group, rather than the name you might like, such as `x`. I have found that it is usually not worth the effort to convince GAP to use your names, but it can be helpful to know it is renaming things internally.